# Connection options from a React Native app to a REST API

Tags: spring, react-native, rest, heroku, p2p

First of all apologies if this is not the exact place to ask this.

We are planning to build a React Native application which is supposed to communicate with a REST API on our backend. We aim to have a Spring based API running on a laptop, for instance, where multiple instances of the application should be able to connect and exchange information

We considered three options -

1. If we host it on our own computer, then we assume that the IP for that would need to be static and should not involve DHCP. We are not sure whether that is feasible, and we do not have much technical knowledge to start off with on this. Is this an approach which could be feasible, and if so what are the things we should be aware of?
2. We of course could host it on the cloud, like on an AWS instance, but we are starting off and are low on budget (very much). We would definitely want to start off with the free tiers and scale it up in the future, but is there a more cost effective option than going down this route?
3. Could we leverage some P2P libraries, like WebRTC or Socket.IO for this purpose? Again, we have a basic understanding of these topics but lack the judgement to determine whether it is something that is going to be workable in the short term and feasible if and when we want to scale the app in the future.

Any insights or comments on this will be highly appreciated. We acknowledge that we probably lack the technical expertise at this point of time to pull the entire thing off, but are willing to learn. If there are maybe any other libraries/frameworks that might be more suitable, please do suggest the same.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

**This option is the cheapest** because you already have the hardware to run your server.

**This solution will ask you to have some knowledge in networking**. Your application needs to **make the request at your public IP and to redirect this request to your computer**. You need to ask your Internet access provider for more information.

The **limitation of this solution come from your hardware and your internet bandwidth.**

Your computer can process a limited amount of requests and the bandwidth limit the number of requests receive too. This can increase the response time of your server exponentially.

**You can buy a better server, increase the bandwidth or create a swarm to avoid this issue**.

Option 2:

This option can be taken if this is a **temporary small scale project**, need to deploy **multiple server across the globe** to reduce the response time of your request, **need to scale dynamically the need in performance** or you **don't want to manage your hardware**.

On a small or big scale project, **buying your own server will be less expensive in the long run.**

**The biggest advantage of this solution is the optimisation** of your need in real time. You can scale up or down the power of your servers in function of the need during the day.

Keep in mind that **these servers exist in the real world and can have some real issue**. For example, [they can catch fire](https://dev.to/yoursunny/ovh-strasbourg-halt-and-catch-fire-data-uploaded-to-the-cloud-4j19).

Another thing to keep in mind is that **a cloud service provider [can shut down your server at any moment for any reason](https://www.businessinsider.fr/us/parler-shutdown-by-amazon-might-not-be-fatal-to-the-social-network-2021-1)**.

Option 3:

This solution **should be used only when you need to send and receive data in real time** (messagery, notification).

A socket connected to your server will consume the resources of your server even idle and increase the response time for the other user.